chrome.py can't write to the filesystem only when django is run as a service
From pyhtml2pdf
converter.convert(f'file:///{path}', pdf_file_path)

On my Ubuntu 20.04 Azure VM, chrome.py doesn't seem to be able to write to pdf_file_path when my django server is run as a service - though it works when I run my django server as python manage.py runserver.
The actual error is :

Error inserting data : Exception occurred in file '/var/www/myProject/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py', line 64: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

which is
determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])

